# Which network interface does my tcp listener listen

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcplistener

I have two network interfaces. I take 192.168.1.100 from eth0 and 192.168.1.227 from eth0. Which nic does my tcp listener listen when i use the code below:

```
tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);
tcpListener.Start();
```

Gateway and subnet mask configurations are different for each nic also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234)` initializes a new listener that listens for incoming connection attempts on the specified local IP address and port 1234.
In your case represents `IPAddress.Any` all local IP addresses.

I hope this will answer your question.

You can find more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcplistener

Answer (score 0):

It's binding to all IP addresses on your computer, not necessarily all NICs, as this will also bind to local loopback, along with any virtual adapters you may have.